# How do I tab to the last form element in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, forms

When submitting a form it's very convenient to use `tab` to switch between form elements.

But when you only need to edit first couple of elements it's tedious to press `tab` until the `Submit` button, which is usually the last one.

Is there a shortcut to switch directly to the last element in form, or better to `Submit` button?

Comment: <shift><tab> should go backwards.

Comment: I don't want to go backwards, I need to go directly to the `submit` button.

Comment: Maybe press `Enter`?

Comment: @Boykodev It's faster than going forwards. There is no [shortcut](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) - see "webpage Shortcuts" -  for going direct to the submit button

Comment: @gronostaj completely forgot you can submit with `Enter`. Thanks, problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a form field different than `textarea` (the multiline text field) submits forms.